# NullPointerException at RecycleView

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview

i've been trying to use the TwoWay lib for a horizonal listview implemention, so i got the RecycleView lib and the TwoWay, but at both run time and the xml i receive this Exception :

```
09-21 01:46:52.148: E/AndroidRuntime(12471): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-21 01:46:52.148: E/AndroidRuntime(12471): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-21 01:46:52.148: E/AndroidRuntime(12471):    at 
com.lifemate.lmmessenger.recycleview.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:1346)
09-21 01:46:52.148: E/AndroidRuntime(12471):    at  
android.view.View.measure(View.java:12881)
09-21 01:46:52.148: E/AndroidRuntime(12471):    at   
android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:599)
09-21 01:46:52.148: E/AndroidRuntime(12471):    at 
android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:381)
09-21 01:46:52.148: E/AndroidRuntime(12471):    at 
android.view.View.measure(View.java:12881)
```

i searched alot and i found out this solution :

```
          bgListView.setHasFixedSize(true);

          mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
          bgListView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

but then i realized that the exception happenes at creating the view before any code is compiled!
does any one have any idea why is this?

Comment: I encountered this problem and solved, check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29997877/1294681) for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume by "the exception happens at creating the view" you mean you are seeing the exception in your editor. This is not a bug, rather a lack of integration with the IDE. A recycler view does not work without a layout manager. Since the code that sets the layout manager is not executed in the IDE, you see this error.

In the future, there will be better integration.

Answer (score 0):

The RecyclerView is in preview release and can contain bugs.

In particular you have to set a *LayoutManager* for your RecyclerView otherwise you will see an exception at Runtime.
No one LayoutManager is provided by default in the current implemetation.