# Android - RecyclerView inside of Fragment - NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to use a `RecyclerView` inside of a `Fragment` (to use it in a `ViewPager`) but I got a `NullPointerException` when I try to execute:

```
 Process: com.yomansk8.birthdaysoundboard, PID: 4448
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.onMeasure(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler, android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$State, int, int)' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:1764)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1456)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

First, this is the layout of my fragment, it's only containing a `RecyclerView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/recyclerDivers"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:clipToPadding="false"/>
```

This is my Fragment:

```
package com.yomansk8.birthdaysoundboard.Fragments;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.yomansk8.birthdaysoundboard.Adapters.RecyclerViewAdapter;
import com.yomansk8.birthdaysoundboard.GenerateDatas;
import com.yomansk8.birthdaysoundboard.MainActivity;
import com.yomansk8.birthdaysoundboard.Models.ViewModel;
import com.yomansk8.birthdaysoundboard.R;
import com.yomansk8.birthdaysoundboard.ScrollManager;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Yohann on 09/03/2015.
 */
public class DiversFragment extends Fragment implements  RecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

private MediaPlayer mPlayer = null;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private GridLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
private  List<ViewModel> items;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_divers, container, false);

    toolbar = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getToolbar();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerDivers);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    items = GenerateDatas.getAmbianceList();


    adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(items);


    /*toolbar.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            ScrollManager manager = new ScrollManager();
            manager.attach(recyclerView);
            manager.addView(toolbar, ScrollManager.Direction.UP);
            manager.setInitialOffset(toolbar.getHeight());
        }
    });*/
    Log.v("TEST", "onCreateView()");
    return v;

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view , Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    Log.v("TEST", "onViewCreated()");
    mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override public void onItemClick(View view, ViewModel viewModel) {
    // Lire le son ici
    Integer sound = getResources().getIdentifier(viewModel.getSound(), "raw", getActivity().getPackageName());
    playSound(sound);
}

private void playSound(int resId) {
    if(mPlayer != null) {
        mPlayer.stop();
        mPlayer.release();
    }
    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), resId);
    mPlayer.start();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(mPlayer != null) {
        mPlayer.stop();
        mPlayer.release();
    }
}

}
```

I've also tried to put the initialisation of my `RecyclerView` inside of `onCreateView` and `onViewCreated`, with no success.

Any idea?

**EDIT :**

Here is the code of my `Adapter` :

```
package com.yomansk8.birthdaysoundboard.Adapters;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.yomansk8.birthdaysoundboard.R;
import com.yomansk8.birthdaysoundboard.Models.ViewModel;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Yohann on 19/02/2015.
 */
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {

private List<ViewModel> items;
private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<ViewModel> items) {

    this.items = items;
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
    this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
}

@Override public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_recycler, parent, false);
    v.setOnClickListener(this);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ViewModel item = items.get(position);
    holder.text.setText(item.getText());
    holder.image.setImageBitmap(null);
    Integer mImage = holder.image.getResources().getIdentifier(item.getImage(), "drawable", holder.image.getContext().getPackageName());
    Picasso.with(holder.image.getContext()).load(mImage).into(holder.image);
    holder.itemView.setTag(item);
}

@Override public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override public void onClick(final View v) {
    // Give some time to the ripple to finish the effect
    if (onItemClickListener != null) {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                onItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, (ViewModel) v.getTag());
            }
        }, 200);
    }
}

protected static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView image;
    public TextView text;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    }
}

public interface OnItemClickListener {

    void onItemClick(View view, ViewModel viewModel);

}
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem as you does. As a temporary way, I make it GONE then visible it when a Button was click, but it's not a good solution, did you solve it eventually after 1 month?

Comment: @Yomansk8  Out of curiosity, why are you using `onViewCreated()` method?  You can do everything you were trying to do in `onCreateView()`.

Comment: At the time of this post, I've used `onViewCreated()` because I had try many solutions to make it work (Has I say in my original post). But since I've moved everything in `onCreateView()`. My problem is now solved, it only was an bad copy/paste from another project... Shame on me... ^^

Comment: i am having my all of initializations and settings in onCreateView() still the error persists :/  doing the same using RV in fragment under ViewPager under sliding TabLayout.

Comment: @MFaisalHyder Have you tried all the solutions given on this thread ? In my case, it was a simple copy/paste error that made me inflate the wrong layout. Otherwise, show us your code so we can have a look on it.

Comment: Hihihih, buddy, my issue was the un initialized recyclerView in 2nd tab layout..!

Answer (score 1):

I think you had used an old revision of recyclerview just like me. I adopted revision `recyclerview-20.0.0` the first release version, and of course the exception occurring. so I upgrade my android sdk, then copy the lastest version `22.1.1`(both support-v4 and recyclerview-v7 jars) into my project's libs, then my project work.

In order to prevent the subsequence guys of my team get confusing of the versions, I naming that two jars to including the revision information :

jars in my project's libs directory :

> android-support-v4-22.1.1.jar
>
> android-support-v7-recyclerview-22.1.1.jar

---

---

---

Before that, I also figure out a solution in revision **20.0.0**, I create a widget named `MyRecyclerView` which extended from RecyclerView, then new a rough LayoutManager in constructors.

```
public class MyRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
    public MyRecyclerView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public MyRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MyRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setLayoutManager(new LayoutManager() {
            @Override
            public LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams() {
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It can work but wasn't the perfect approach.

---

---

BTW, as @yigit said in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25966364/1294681), this is **a lack of integration with the IDE** and **In the future, there will be better integration**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout for your fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/recyclerDivers"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried with your xml but always got the error.

Comment: When i put my RecyclerView directly in an Activity instead of Fragment, it perfectly work. So I dont think it was a problem with the Adapter. But I can add the code of the Adapter if you want ;-)

Comment: Have you tried move all codes from `onViewCreated` to `onCreateView`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried to put it into `onViewCreated`, `onCreateView`, `onAttach` and `onCreatedActivity` but none of them seems to work.

Comment: My RecyclerView is in fragment, work fine. I am using `onViewCreate`, I guess at least `setLayoutManager` should be done before `onCreateView` return view.

Comment: I'm ok with this, and actually `setLayoutManager` occurs before `onCreateView` return the view. But it's just like my `layoutManager` was reset to null after that...