# android RecyclerView onMeasure nullpointer

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I wanna use recyclerview, but null pointer has appeared.

So I searched this issue, They said i have to make LinearLayoutManager set like below, I did it.:

```
setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context))
```

But, It doesn't work.

My error log is :

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:1694)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16628)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16628)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:883)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16628)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16628)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16628)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16628)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16628)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2298)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16628)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5610)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5137)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:718)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My code :

```
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(IndexActivity.this , 2 );
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

xml :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/index_gridview_horizontal_spacing"
            android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/index_gridview_vertical_spacing"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView" />
```

This problem was solved by changing gradle.

My reference is here : beecanvas.com/yjcSh8Tp

Comment: May be problem is with your `context`. May be it is null.

Comment: my context? ..  
that's code inside initView() method and initView() is inside IndexActicity's onCreate.  why my context is problem?

Comment: In which line are you getting Null pointer.

Comment: show your `initView()` method.

Comment: You have no need for numColumns since you define it in your GridLayoutManager, horizontal and vertical spacing can be achieved using ItemDecorator. You should try removing these attributes from the XML. I know that some attributes, even though they are available through XML cause problems with the recyclerView, like animateLayoutChanged for example.

Comment: GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(IndexActivity.this , 2 );
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
            mImageLoader = MainApplication.VolleySingleton.getInstance(IndexActivity.this).getImageLoader();
            mAdapter = new CanvasAdapter(IndexActivity.this , map , mImageLoader);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

Comment: what is this code? for whose comment?

Comment: that's my initView() method   and  for   Piyush Gupta

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26737113/java-lang-nullpointerexception-at-android-support-v7-widget-recyclerview-onmeasu

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(
    R.id.recycler_view);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
recyclerView.setAdapter(new NumberedAdapter(30));
```

Here I have used span count of 2, you will have 30 elements, you can modify as per your need. Hope this helps you.

Comment: I think my problem is other thing. but  your answer is useful !

Comment: ok... Can you tell in which line are you getting null pointer

Comment: oh... i comment recyclerview's code , but same error executed.
so i deleted recyclerview in .xml  error was gone.

Comment: it was 
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/index_gridview_horizontal_spacing"
  android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/index_gridview_vertical_spacing"
  android:numColumns="2"
  android:id="@+id/recyclerView" />

Comment: i removed 
android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/index_gridview_horizontal_spacing" android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/index_gridview_vertical_spacing" android:numColumns="2" 

and clicked Design Tab in xml window, 
" Rendering Problems" is shown.
the new recyclerview does not yet work in studio. we are working on a fix. (open issue 72117, show exception)....

Comment: Ok Ok the same error is shown to me but in application it works.

Comment: it's work ! 
i changed my gradle 
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.0'   
->
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74097/discussion-between-kesh1234-and-jihoon-kim).

Answer (score 1):

have you used an old revision of recyclerview? you can check my another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29997877/1294681) for details, hope it help.

Comment: Thank you !
But, this problem was solved. 
I changed recyclerview's version to 21.0.0 from 22. (That's all . )

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using wrong `GridLayoutManager`. Please make sure you have `import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager`, and then:

```
//for Activity
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));

or //for Fragment
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2));
```

should be ok.

[**UPDATE**]
You only can set one `LayoutManager` for `RecyclerView`, `LinearLayoutManager` or `GridLayoutManager` or `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`, not both of them. For your case, just set `GridLayoutManager`.

Hope this help!

Comment: thank you for your help. but that GridLayoutManager is  android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.
And  IndexActivity is activity , but getActivity() is fragment's method.

Comment: Are you also using `setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context))` in your codes?

Comment: @jihoonkim, suppose still your `RecyclerView.LayoutManager` problem, nothing else

Comment: what is - " Rendering Problems" is shown. the new recyclerview does not yet work in studio. we are working on a fix. (open issue 72117, show exception) -  ?? 
why i can't use this?  other people already use recyclerview .. T T

Comment: When your `Layout` has problem, then you will get `Rendering Problems` in Studio